# Spigot on heroku using docker

Tags: docker, heroku, minecraft

I'm trying to host a spigot minecraft server on heroku using docker. I know that heroku doesn't really support tcp so I use ngrok(localhost tunneling) to get around this. The image is based on the official openjdk 8-jre image and starts spigot and ngrok and then gets the ngrok address and uploads it to a pastebin service called ix.io. Everything works fine when I run the docker image locally but when i try to run it on heroku it sais:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
State changed from starting to crashed
```

the complete log can be found here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paperbenni/6c1f4567dbf02cda299230eeb3391fc0/raw/7832444ed358131c9c6c57e330baa62b74cd113e/heroko%2520docker%2520spigot%2520logs

What is going on here? Does there have to be some sort of web service using things like nginx which can be accessed from a web browser in order for the app to be considered valid?(long and probably wrong spelled sentence, I know) I don't really get what's going on here.

Sidenote: there are some memory errors in the logs. The container runs fine locally when limited to 512mb RAM, so maybe someone could help me out with that.

Comment: I don't believe this is related to programming. Might be better to ask at SuperUser

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Check that your port is right and make sure that you still have heroku run time. That could be the error. Hope I helped! **:)**

EDIT: When you run your server, it runs through "dynos". These dynos can only have 512mb RAM. If you world uses more than that, consider making a smaller world or lower the RAM.

Lower RAM: https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/server-optimization-lowering-ram.10999/

It should be in properties xml file etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I now figured out how to do it with openshift. Also I was iin fact using more than 512mb RAM.

Comment: Glad I helped. Make sure to put my as the solution if I was. :)

Comment: @PaperBenni Hi, do you have discord? I'd like to speak to you about how you did it. I'm curious on how to do it myself. If you do, may I please have your tag? This is mine: WetNoodle#9546 Thanks. If you don't have discord, please comment back with another way I could contact you thanks.

Comment: I have discord.

Comment: If you could friend me that would be great! Thanks. :)